# Using Google Play Quests in Unity 4

Tags: android, google-play-games

Is it possible to use google play games quests in versions of unity below 5? I am using Unity 4.5.2f1, and am using the latest google play games plugin. When i add this code to show quests:

```
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Quests.ShowAllQuestsUI(
            (QuestUiResult result, IQuest quest, IQuestMilestone milestone) => {
            // ...
    });
```

the scipts referenced(QuestUiResult,IQues and IQuesMilestone) don't exist in the current context.

Am i doing something wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work in 4.5.  The only issue I have experienced is importing the sample unitypackages does not work too well, but adding the source manually worked.

From the [TrivalQuest](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/samples/TrivialQuest/Source/Assets/TrivialQuest/TrivialQuest.cs) sample, you should be able to call something like:

```
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.Quests;

 public void ViewQuests()
    {
        Debug.Log("clicked:ViewQuests");
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Quests.ShowAllQuestsUI(
            (QuestUiResult result, IQuest quest, IQuestMilestone milestone) =>
            {
                if (result == QuestUiResult.UserRequestsQuestAcceptance)
                {
                    Debug.Log("User Requests Quest Acceptance");
                    AcceptQuest(quest);
                }

                if (result == QuestUiResult.UserRequestsMilestoneClaiming)
                {
                    Debug.Log("User Requests Milestone Claim");
                    ClaimMilestone(milestone);
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) works like a charm. All i needed was to include using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.Quests. One thing i am still stuck on however, is the reward system for quests. Say i have a value of coins in player prefs, how do i add 10 coins to that as a reward for completing the quest?, Thanks again @Clayton Wilkinson

Comment: Also, an issue i found when importing the latest GPGS plugin is that in one of the scripts is references Texture2D.blackTexture, which i don't think exists in Unity 4, so i had to change it to equal null to fix compile errors.

Comment: thanks for feedback!  The reward for a quest is up to you -  the data file assoicated with the quest on the Play Console contains the data.  For example, it could be json and then read it when the quest is claimed.

Comment: I still don't quite understand how i access the data from the json file in my unity project. I have created another question. Do you mind having a look? Thanks. @Clayton Wilkinson